# gnuplot to display an equation title nicely with Latex, but I would like to avoid producing a tex output for that, that I don't know how to handle

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I'm executing a:

```bash
gnuplot testGNUPlot.dat -p
```

with `testGNUPlot.dat` having this content:

```
plot [-4:4] [-30:5] -x**2+2*x-3 title '$ -x^2-2x-3 $'
```

I'm receiving this result, which isn't the expected one:

[image]

`$ -x^2-2x-3 $` isn't transformed, through *Latex* near the curve legend to its expected *-x²-2x-3* form.
(it's more obvious if I try to display for title: `$\sqrt{-x^2-2x-3}$` : the square root symbol will never be translated to its graphical counterpart).

How shall I achieve this?

I would like to avoid a tex output, that is currently leading me to messages like `epslatex terminal cannot write to standard output`, that I don't know how to manage.

(I only need my windows to display the formula correctly near its violet symbol).

If some tex directives are really needed, can they be managed a way they ensure that the script can still, however :

- execute from a command line
- produce a windows with the curve displayed?

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? If the answer solved your problem, please check the check mark indicating that the question is answered. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me with Windows 10 and a MiKTeX installation.

Ingredients:

- `cairolatex` terminal
- LaTeX installation with `pdflatex`
- PDF viewer (e.g. SumatraPDF for Windows will automatically show the updated PDF, whereas Acrobat Reader will block gnuplot from (over)writing the PDF file)

Either the path of the `pdflatex` executable is already in your system path or alternatively you can give the absolute path in the gnuplot command.

- the gnuplot script will create the files `SO75712292.tex` and `SO75712292-inc.pdf`
- `pdflatex` will create the final `SO75712292.pdf`.

**Script:**

```
### create LaTeX formatted output
reset session

set term cairolatex standalone size 10cm,7cm
OUTPUT = "SO75712292.tex"
set output OUTPUT

plot [-4:4] [-30:5] -x**2+2*x-3 title '$ -x^2-2x-3 $'

set output
system(sprintf('pdflatex.exe %s', OUTPUT))
### end of script
```

**Result:** (screenshot of `SO75712292.pdf` from SumatraPDF)

[image]